# mysql "IN" condition with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, conditional-statements

I need to execute the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mp_sizes 
WHERE size_id IN(SELECT size_ids FROM mp_size_categories 
WHERE category_id = '3' AND sub_category_id = '5');
```

When I run the below query it return me 3 records.

```
SELECT * FROM mp_sizes WHERE size_id IN(3,2,4);
```

Also when I run the sub query it showing me the correct result.

```
SELECT size_ids FROM mp_size_categories 
WHERE category_id = '3' AND sub_category_id = '5';
```

The above query gives the result `3, 2, 4`.

But when I use that in sub query it returns only one record. It return the size details of the first value (3) only.

How can I get the results of all 3 sizes (3, 2, 4)?

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM mp_sizes a
LEFT JOIN mp_size_categories b ON b.size_ids = a.size_id
WHERE b.category_id IN (3, 5); - not tested , hope this helps

Comment: I couldn't use like this. Because the size_ids field on the mp_size_categories table is varchar field. And it having not a single integer but it is having all size ids with comma separate as like 3,2,4

Comment: do you have a sql fiddle sample?

Comment: Using many-to-many values in a comma-separated list breaks rules of database normalization. Using group_concat and find_in_set you might obtain the desired result set. I created a sql fiddle for you - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c078/2 - not sure the schema is right - at least is a start point. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using `JOIN`? (which is faster)

```
 SELECT * FROM mp_sizes, mp_size_categories
 WHERE size_id = size_ids AND category_id = '3'
 AND sub_category_id = '5';
```

Comment: I believe most people would prefer `... FROM mp_sizes JOIN mp_size_categories ON size_id = size_ids WHERE ...` (but this doesn't actually answer OP's question).

Comment: As you see my sub query (SELECT size_ids FROM mp_size_categories WHERE category_id = '3' AND sub_category_id = '5') will return a string as 3,2,4. Because the field size_ids is a varchar field and it having 3,2,4 as value in it.

Comment: Then you might have to do some string parsing in PHP (or something else). I don't know if it is possible to extract the values 3, 2 and 4 from the string "3,2,4" using mysql only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nested query, I think you should use the following query with **Join** to get exact same result and it should be even faster than sub query:

```
select * from mp_sizes as mpsizes 
join mp_size_categories as mpsizecategories 
on mpsizes.size_id = mpsizecategories.size_ids 
where mpsizecategories.category_id = '3' 
AND mpsizecategories.sub_category_id = '5';
```